# I am trying to free some part of data and mark its rest with specific integer value to indicate that it is not a valid pointer. (Not an array)

Tags: c++, pointers

```
bool isPointerValid(void *vd)
{
    if (*(int*)vd == 22049929)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void operator delete(void *vd)
{
    if (!isPointerValid(vd))
    {
        //DOUBLE DELETION
        throw;
    }

    realloc(vd, 4);
    *((int*)vd) = 22049929;
}
```

I am reallocating datas instead of totally freeing them. And write a specific integer value to that reallocated data. That way, I can check a pointer that is deleted or not with looking its first 4 bytes.

I am doing that reducing size operation to save memory.

But there are two different problems here:

1- realloc function is not guarenteeing that you are going to have the same location after reallocation. Even if there is enough space for 4 bytes in memory at that location. We know if our initial data is larger than 4 bytes there must be enough space.

2- Some datatypes can be smaller than 4 bytes. And there can be not enough space for 4 bytes in memory at that location. It occurs often when you store these small data types in a container. We can solve it with reallocating every data type to 1 byte, but there is a too much possiblity to match that one byte data to a valid pointer's first byte.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @piripiri I am asking solution for problems

Comment: Is `22049929` special in some way? Or have you just not `#define`ed it yet?

Comment: @undeadherbs it is just some value nothing special, it can be another value. It just means the pointer is deleted.

Comment: To remark unused memory with a certain bit pattern (as in `(int)22049929`) makes it error-prone. What if the _used_ memory incidentally contains this value in its first bytes? (This would be true more or less for any other integer value as well.)

Comment: May be, you try to solve something for what already solutions exist. For dangling pointers/wild pointers have a search for smart pointers. Since C++11, they are part of the C++ standard libraries. To prevent memory fragmentation, you may search for "memory pools". (I did this just today as I already gave this recommendation some hours ago.)

Comment: sorry, but what's the point of this anyway? if you're having trouble with double-deletions, your problems are elsewhere

Comment: @Scheff Yes there is a possibility, but a small possiblity maybe some double check system can solve the problem for that. If I solve mentioned problems first.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x it is not just for preventing double deletions, it also can prevent using of unvalid pointers. You can check pointers' validity with this system if it works.

Comment: The probability could be 1/2^32 (assuming 32 bit integers) though some integer values are used probably much more often. If these bytes are not used for `(int)` storage the probability probable comes closer to 1/2^32. (Probable.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff If the system works I can check my old codes which didn't used smart pointers.

Comment: Btw. If you compile in VS with debug mode, VS does what you try to achieve. (And it adds a lot more of other debug code.) On Linux, valgrind is a tool to look for memory issues... (Sorry, if you feel I try to discourage you...)

Comment: if you're overwriting `operator delete`, then are you also writing `operator new`? (you should be newing with malloc if you're intending to use realloc in when deleting). you can make `new` always allocate at least 4 bytes.

Comment: @Scheff I know all, don't worry. And I am trying to make an efficient system to check these bugs.

Comment: I'd also suggest not using realloc because of the non-guarantee, just leave the memory. if you're only using this as a debugging tool, hopefully you trigger any problems before you run out of memory

Comment: @vu1p3n0x your suggestion can solve problem 2, I think.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Leaving the memory, is an option yes, but in big programs memory is going to be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried your code? As others point out, use DEBUG build to help find memory problem. Your code can create as much problem as it solve. It is very fragile if you forget one check. Also, I am not sure that you make the difference between a pointer and the data it point to. Obviously, your code would fails if good data happen to match 22049929. Finally, I would say that if you do not understand what you do, **then you don’t want to write such code** that may cause many problems.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to write through `vd` after reallocing it

Answer (score 0):

The best sentinel value would be `(void*) nullptr`. Inventing your own sentinels is asking for problems.